# Are Science Fair Questions On-Topic?

Tags: support, on-topic-ness

Are questions about middle and high school science fairs on-topic? Of course, they wouldn't be about the *content*, they would be about the *process* of doing the research in the fair.

Comment: In particular, how would a question about middle school science fairs be related to life in academia (graduate school, master's level or higher). Is there some relation, for example, "will participation in a middle school science fair affect my children's future prospects in succeeding in graduate school?" will be on topic, however, most questions about high school science fairs will not be applicable to academia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will strongly depend on the particulars of the question.

- Questions related to science fairs per se will generally be off-topic as being undergraduate or below.
- Questions related to the specific topics of research will typically be off-topic on this site but on-topic on another StackExchange site (e.g., Biology.SE).
- Questions about general research process and presentation, whether to mention your success in a grad school application, etc., would generally be on-topic here.

Comment: "Questions about general research process and presentation" are only on topic if they could also apply to graduate-level researchers, according to the help center.